# Validate datatable to not upload values if column has blank values in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

Currently, I am uploading an Excel file to upload and display data in a form. So I am validating with basic that `dt` should not be null and count should be greater than `0`. But also I want one validation that if `dt` column is bank for ex:  `STATE` column first row in my below image then it should prompt an alert that excel has a blank column. How can I achieve it.

[![IMAGE][1]][1]

Below is what I tried but it is still excepting the blank values.

```
private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension, string isHDR)
    {
        string conStr = "";
        switch (Extension)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"]
                         .ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"]
                          .ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);

        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        connExcel.Open();

        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();            

        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count <= Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["excelUploadSize_JioAF"]))  // check for 200 records
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Max upload size is 200 rows');", true);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Excel is blank..!!');", true);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the columns and rows to achieve the above requirement. The below code should help you to validate all the columns are rows.

```
bool hasBlankColumn = false;

foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    bool isColumnBlank = false;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row[column].ToString()))
        {
            isColumnBlank = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isColumnBlank)
    {
        hasBlankColumn = true;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Excel has a blank column: " + column.ColumnName + "');", true);

        break; // Exit the loop if a blank column is found
    }
}
if (!hasBlankColumn)
{
    // Proceed with your logic for valid data
}
```

Comment: I want to check blank for all the columns, then what can be done ?

Comment: @Nad the code is updated to support all the columns, please check and upvote the answer.

Comment: sure Mayank, let me check and update you

Comment: in `// Proceed with your logic for valid data` if I want to iterate through each dt rows then `dt.Rows[i]["A6-NEID"].ToString();` `i` is giving error

Comment: I have blank column in `STATE` but still its going in `if (!hasBlankColumn)`

Comment: @Nad can you collaborate on the exception, I guess the original requirement to validate an empty column is achieved. This is something, I recommended if you want to validate additional stuff related with the data.

Comment: @Nad I have updated the code and found a bug in the earlier version, it should work now.

Comment: Hi Mayank, can u help with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77149696/compare-2-datatables-with-column-name-a6-neid-and-merge-the-distinct-data-in-thi